# How can I Rank() the value of a column based on

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, window-functions

In SQL, how can I rank() based on values on a column based on condition of another column?

I have a table like this. How can I rank based on value of 'NO' if `Class is 2`?

The source is :

| No | Name | Class |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | reema | 2 |
| 102 | kriya | 1 |
| 103 | meena | 3 |
| 104 | carlin | 1 |
| 105 | dhiren | 2 |
| 106 | hiren | 2 |
| 107 | mahir | 3 |
| 108 | nishi | 1 |

The result

| No | Name | Class | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | reema | 2 | 1 |
| 102 | kriya | 1 |  |
| 103 | meena | 3 |  |
| 104 | carlin | 1 |  |
| 105 | dhiren | 2 | 2 |
| 106 | hiren | 2 | 3 |
| 107 | mahir | 3 |  |
| 108 | nishi | 1 |  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rank studens within each class with `row_number()` and `partition by class`.

To ignore classes you are not interested in, a `case` expression comes handy:

```
select t.*,
    case when class = 2 
        then row_number() over(partition by class order by no) 
    end as rnk
from mytable t
```